# Bash Script is not running using crontab?

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

I am new to cron job as I have a bash script which help to restart the program when I am using this script manually its working fine but when I am using it using cron job its not. I have made the script executable, I have added shebang in the bash file but its not working could anybody can help me to find out what could be the reason that its not working.

```
*/1 * * * * /home/pi/Schreibtisch/PSTecSoftware/AccessControlRepository/BashScripts/AccessControl_restart.sh
```

Whenever I am giving a command in cron job to reboot and kill it is working but not able to access the path of the bash script. Does any one have any idea regarding this.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Have you checked your logs (in `/var/log`, possibly `syslog`, `auth.log` or `cron.log`) for cron-related errors? Also, to rule out simple issues: is that cron job owned (and run) by the  `pi` user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `at` jobs, a `cron` job does not automatically include a user's environment.

If a `cron` job uses environment variables such as PATH, aliases, or functions that are defined in shell initialization scripts such as ~/.profile, these scripts can be sourced at the top of the `cron` job script.

Alternatively, any additional information such as environmental or shell variables needed by the `cron` job can also be added directly at the top of the `cron` job script.